# form with errors massage in HAML rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I `m change .erb files in .haml. I have such a form:

```
<% form_for :ticket do |f| %>
<% if @ticket.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being  saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<p><b>department</b><br/>
<%= select("ticket", "department_id", Department.find(:all).collect{ |d| [ d.name, d.id] }) %>
</p>

<%= submit_tag 'make a request' -%>
<% end %>
```

The above mentioned works... but 
for me it`s very complicated task... to convert it to haml
very appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a resource such as [HTML2Haml](http://html2haml.heroku.com/) which will get you close.

With a little practice, you'll find converting from ERb to Haml, straightforward and fun.
The primary conversions are:

- `<% foo` ==> `- foo`
- `<%= foo` ==> `= foo`
- `<foo id="bar" class="baz">`  ==> `%foo#bar.baz`

Comment: +1 for using html2haml. I lvoe that tool. Sometimes it gets confused but more often than not it gets me what I need.